# Is it possible to change material overtime by keyframes in swipe effect?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

So I watched disney frozen, and at the let it go song, i was wondering, how to change the material texture in a swipe effect (if I do it on AnimAll add on, it just changing dragly, so the texture are really messed up). The point is, i want to change texture from feet to head by swipe effect by horizontal line , not dragging all the texture constantly.
Sorry if my english is bad, im me and im new to blender

Comment: Please place an image in your question to help explain your question to others.

Comment: I understand what you are asking. What you want is having two shaders and an animated mask between them. The shaders should be mapped static so the textures don't move, but the blending mask should have Z-mapping axis animated, to reveal the second shader from bottom to the top. This can be all done inside 1 material in Cycles.

Comment: Most likely the swipe effect is a post production effect, where two identical characters are rendered (the only difference is clothes etc) and compositted on-top of a background render. Then a mask is used to reveal more and more of one character over the duration of maybe 30 frames / 1 second (or however long it needs to be)

Answer (score 3):

Using a simple gradient and color ramp will allow you to control two different materials for the same object:

[image]

Then is just a matter of animating the value for the mapping.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blender allows you to animate values of materials and textures. You can add keyframes to the sliders/numbers in the Materials and Textures GUI. Changing from one texture to another could be done by using a "Blend" texture in stencil mode between two other textures and animating it's offset.