# Combining two IMAGES so they fade into one another in a gradient or transition

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image

I've checked all the other threads on this question and there are ones similar but not quite explaining the effect I'm looking for.

Essentially in cycles, I want to fade a sand unit into a clay unit gradually transitioning from one to the other. The image shown has a harsh, unrealistic change that makes my already amateur equipment look appalling!!

[image: Sand to clay]

I've set it up with two planes (1 Sand (below) and a similar Clay 1. Intuition says I should probably be using only one plane to get the gradient I want but this is what I have so far..

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: see the node setup in this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43912/1853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your intuition is correct, you don't even need to remake your materials.
Just use a single plane, and use a gradient texture as a mix value in the *Factor* socket of a *Mix Shader* node to fade between the two.

Then copy paste your two materials into the same shader tree and mix them together.

You may use a color ramp node to control the transition.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replay mate, I have the fade working but I can't get the displacement textures on. I have two separate images (1 for clay and 1 for sand). I can't work out how to get these on using this method. I just have two plain colours fading into each other. Although the fade is nice!

Comment: Hum I missed that detail. You can use the same exact technique to mix your displacement textures. Just use a color mix node instead, and the same color ramp as factor socket input, then connect it to the material output node displacement socket as you did before.

Comment: Brilliant! Cheers man, had me confused for a while then, I just needed to re-UV-unwrap it and it's worked perfectly. Thank you very much