# Blender texturing effects

Tags: animation, mesh, texturing, light

I would like to create in blender of animations light on the walls of a cube of rubik, for example illuminate a cube of one of the many faces at the time of a rotation. And I would like to use this animation on a texture hive , maybe managing to create bright light animations controllable and adjustable on the appropriate individual hexagons of the texture, gradually, I don’t know if you explain.

[image]

[Texture on RenderHub](https://www.renderhub.com/chamsb11/bee-hive-texture)

Comment: Welcome Albizz. Hard to follow your post. Can you please add an image of what you're trying to achieve to your question?

Comment: yeah im new, i try to post an image but i don't know how.

Comment: See: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a newbie, but the only thing I could think of is to change the lighting in precise spots.  What could be done with nodes? So I went looking.

I found this video for the basic question of making a section of the texture light up, in an example of making "lava cracks" glow. But it doesn't address the question of changing what lights up over time. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEdA5pP5Wrk

Here's another that includes texture painting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF3hj5s5pr0

This one shows you (toward the end) how to animate a texture by keyframing the changes to it. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xa7wJZBuKXw

And finally, here is another Stack Exchange answer on how to change textures as an animations plays. 
[Is it possible to change material overtime by keyframes in swipe effect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43789/is-it-possible-to-change-material-overtime-by-keyframes-in-swipe-effect)

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice seems fantastic, I immediately start working to experience something. Thanks again